# React Native - Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React Child (Using Node JS for backend)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

here I'm trying to have the sum of orders and the sum of their quantity in which I use **Node JS** for my backend. The problem is whenever I run my code -- my fetch functions seems not working properly or I'm missing something that I'm not aware.

But using postman, my API is working with the expected output. Buuut if I use it in my react-native code it show some errors.

[image: Sum using postman]
[image: Quantity using postman]

Here's my code for backend:

OrderNo.js (models) //Backend

```
var Task = {
    Sum:function(id,callback) {
        return db.query("SELECT SUM(order_amount) AS TotalAmountOrdered FROM orders where order_no=?",[id],callback);
    },
}
```

OrderNo.js (router) //Backend

```
var Task = require('../models/OrderNo');
router.get('/ForSum/:id?', (req, res, next) => {
    Task.Sum(req.params.id,function(err,rows) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

NumOrder.js (models) //Backend

```
var Task = {
    NumOrder:function(id,callback) {
        return db.query("SELECT SUM(order_quantity) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM orders where order_no=?",[id],callback);
    },
}
```

NumOrder.js (router) //Backend

```
var Task = require('../models/NumOrder');
router.get('/num/:id?', (req, res, next) => {
    Task.NumOrder(req.params.id,function(err,rows) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's my code for React-Native

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            orderDet: this.props.navigation.state.params.orderDet,
            numOrder: [],
            TotalSum: [],
        };
    }
    fetchSum = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.104:3308/OrderNo/ForSum/" + this.state.orderDet)
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ TotalSum: json })
    }
    fetchNumOrders = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.104:3308/NumOrder/num/" + this.state.orderDet )
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ numOrder: json })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchNumOrders();
        this.fetchSum();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Number of Orders: { this.state.numOrder }</Text>
                <Text>Total Amount: ₱{ this.state.TotalSum }</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: This is the error for Sum]
[image: This is the error for Quantity]

And here is my DB

**PS: **I also tried " json[0].order_no " on each of my fetch function and there's no error, but my output is empty.

[image]

[image: DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response object in the `Postman`, you need to do the following

```
this.state = {
        orderDet: this.props.navigation.state.params.orderDet,
        numOrder: null,
        TotalSum: null,
};

fetchSum = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.104:3308/OrderNo/ForSum/" + this.state.orderDet)
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ TotalSum: json[0].TotalAmountOrdered })
    }

fetchNumOrders = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.104:3308/NumOrder/num/" + this.state.orderDet )
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ numOrder: json[0].TotalItemsOrdered })
    }
```

Comment: It works! thank you sir, so it is the alias that should be written, right? why?

Comment: Doesn't matter , you just need to take care not to render objects directly in react, just the values. If there is an array, then use `map` function and so on.. Check examples to know more.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you cannot have object or array as the child the component i.e. `<Text>`. You can only have string or number displayed inside the component.

```
<Text>Number of Orders: { this.state.numOrder[0].TotalAmountOrdered }</Text>// Inside {} value of variable should be string or number not array or object
```

The error is that you are setting value of `this.state.numOrder` an array